# Problems with application startup and Backbone.Marionette Modules

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Unfortunately, I've problems while understanding the startup of Backbone.Marionette modules and submodules. The initializers are called multiple times instead of being called one time each.

What do I need to do to make things work in foreseeable manner?

```
PP = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

PP.bind('start', function() {
    console.log('application start');

    PP.module('Routing').start();
    PP.module('Products').start();
});

PP.module('Routing', {
    startWithApp: false,
    define: function(Routing, PP, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
        Routing.addInitializer(function() {
            console.log('Routing.init');
        });                
    }
});

PP.module('Routing.ProductsRouting', {
    startWithApp: false,
    define: function(ProductsRouting, PP, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
        ProductsRouting.addInitializer(function() {
            console.log('ProductsRouting.init');
        });
    }
});

PP.module('Products', {
    startWithApp: false,
    define: function(Products, PP, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
        Products.addInitializer(function() {
            console.log('Products.init');
        });
    }
});

$(function() {
    PP.start();
});
```

(code also available as [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzeHb/110/))

The code above outputs this lines in the console:

- application start
- Routing.init
- ProductsRouting.init
- Routing.init
- ProductsRouting.init
- Products.init
- Products.init

And this is what I expected:

- application start
- Routing.init
- Products.init

And if you decide to automatically start all the modules with your app (startWithApp: true in all modules and without manually starting Routing and Products modules) the output is this:

- Routing.init
- ProductsRouting.init
- ProductsRouting.init
- Products.init
- application start

Answer (score 3):

this is fixed w/ v0.9.7 https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/changelog.md#v097-view-commit-logs

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by implementing this [github pull request](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/pull/208) on Backbone.Marionette. But maybe Derick Bailey (creator of Backbone.Marionette) has his own opinions on this?

Comment: I want to add one question: How can I control the initialization of modules without starting them in a manual way? I regularly step into undefined methods which aren't initialized during an automatic startup. In my understanding, the [BBCloneMail reference application](https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail) should have the same problems with the current version of Backbone.Marionette (0.9.6). I only try to apply the used opinions.

Comment: that pull request fixes it. trying to find time to get it merged in and released.

Comment: Thanks. Do you already know about the different intialization of modules and submodules which yields in undefined methods during an automatic startup (compared to Marionette 0.9.3)? Or is it intentionally and I would have to restructure my app? If I made no mistakes in my implementation, BBCloneMail should have the same problems, too. The only reason of manually starting my modules is the circumvention of these problems...

Comment: i'm not sure what the issue is you're trying to describe. can you post this on the mailing list, with more detail? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/backbone-marionette

Comment: Fortunately, now there's no reason to post this on the mailing list as I made the mistake myself. While fiddling with my test code (http://jsfiddle.net/xzeHb/124/) it's now clear, that I've have to precisely choose the type of the addInitializers. With module based initializers the loading order of your javascript files or the order of the manual module startup are playing a significant role. That's not the case with app based initializers. Then I can bind to the start event and all methods are defined and ready to use. This is also the way you choosed in BBCloneMail. I just overlooked that.

Comment: With that said, I'm really looking forward to how you use the new Backbone.Marionette features in [BBCloneMail](https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail) maybe combined with tests for the different modules.

Comment: I'm working on a rebuild of BBCloneMail in the dev branch... it's very minimal so far, and it's definitely a work in progress. Still trying to decide whether I like the approach I'm taking, for testing and for modules. It will evolve a lot, but there is a little bit of progress in the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still having an issue with modules seeming to load in the wrong order - the solution for me was the location of `Backbone.history.start()`.

Here was my problem:

**bootstrap.js**

```
App.start();
```

**App.js**

```
App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

var _AppRouter = Backbone.AppRouter.extend({
  appRoutes: { 
    "" : "getStarted"
  },
  controller: App
});

App.getStarted = function() {
  console.log(App.MyModule.myMethod);  // undefined
  App.MyModule.myMethod();
}

App.addInitializer(function() {
  new _AppRouter();
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

**App.MyModule.js**

```
App.module("MyModule", function(MyModule, App) {
  MyModule.myMethod = function() {
    console.log("in myMethod");       // never gets called
  }
});
```

App.MyModule.myMethod is undefined in this example, so nothing happens when the app starts.

The problem, I discovered, is where I was calling `Backbone.history.start()`. I moved this call to my bootstrap.js file, so that I'm only calling my routes *after* all of my app modules have been properly initialized.

**bootstrap.js**

```
App.start();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Easy peazy.